# How can I set Text Color (and Background color) in PPT 2007

Tags: c++, powerpoint

I am trying to set the color of a text in PPT from my C++ project.

The attribute `TextRange->Font->Color` cannot be modified ?!

I should feel much obliged if you can provide me any further help.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the font color of a TextRange in PowerPoint from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247135/how-can-i-change-the-font-color-of-a-textrange-in-powerpoint-from-c)

Answer (score 0):

Font.Color is an object, not a property.

To change the color you need to change Font.Color.RGB to a long representing the color you want.  Or change Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor to a long representing the index of the theme color you want.

Ah. But I'm speaking in VBA-tongues.  My Longs are probably your Integers.

Comment: Color is a property of Font. And it is a pointer to the object ColorFormat. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj228306.aspx)

The only two similar methods are :
`void Putignorethis ( mso::MsoRGBType ignorethis );`
Which I guess means, this functionality is not supported.
And then:
`void PutObjectThemeColor (enum mso::MsoThemeColorIndex ObjectThemeColor );`
If I check the enum mso::MsoThemeColorIndex, I see that it is not what I am really looking for.

Comment: Most of the PowerPoint documentation on that site is incomplete, useless or just plain wrong.  Sometimes all three.  I wouldn't pay a great deal of attention to it.

Comment: Yes, it's true. My best documentation is to check by myself the decompiled API.